# Remove all zero values from string PHP

Tags: php, split, substr, strpos

I have a string like this:

```
14522354265300000000000
```

I want to display it without zero values, how I can do this?  I do this

```
$pos = strpos($route, '0');
$length = count(str_split($route));
$a = $length - $pos;
$a = substr($route, 0, $a);
```

but it remove `3` in the end of string. Can somebody help me?

Additional:
If string will be `123088888880`, I want make it `123`.

Comment: `rtrim($string, '0');`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: *"Additional: If string will be 123088888880, I want make it 123."* - *Oh,* the plot thickens, [from your original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28964543/1). I had a feeling they'd be more to this from the *get go*. Ah, human instincts, *eh?!*

Comment: So you don't want to remove all zero values but cut the string before the first 0? Use `explode('0', $route, 1)` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a nice algo:

```
<?php

$string = "14522354265300000000000";
$new_string = '';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string) ; $i++){
    if($string[$i] != '0'){
        $new_string .= $string[$i];
    }
}

echo $new_string;

?>
```

rtrim is only if you have zero's at end of string :)

Comment: `str_replace('0', '', $str)`?

Comment: Yea you've got a point.. thanks ;)

Comment: So `12340567` becomes `1234567` which is probably not desired by OP

Comment: @kingkero It seems so, but the title is certainly misleading. Ooops, it seems the OP does want that...

Comment: he said that he wants no zero's values. Thats what I understood from the question... anyways this case is closed lol

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) for this:

```
echo rtrim("14522354265300000000000", "0"); // outputs: 145223542653
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rtrim('14522354265300000000000', '0')`